# How can I speed up an iteration in python?

Tags: python, performance, iteration

I was wondering if you could help me to speed up my python script.

I have two lists:

```
a=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']

b=['b','f','g','j']
```

I want to create a list that will contain elements of b, but will have a length of a, with elements not in b replaced by something else, let's say `'-999'`. Also, instead of having the actual elements (a,b,c...) I want to substitute that with the element's index from b. So it would look like that:

```
c=['-999',0,'-999','-999','-999', 1, 2,'-999','-999',3]
```

My code for now is:

```
c=[]

counter=0

for each in a:
    if each in b:
        c.append(counter)
        counter+=1
    else:
        c.append('-999')
```

It works fine, however, in real life my list a is 600 000 elements long, and there are actually 7 b lists that I need to iterate them over, all between 3k and 250k elements as well.

Any ideas on how to speed this up?

Comment: `there are actually 7 b lists that I need to iterate them over, all between 3k and 250k elements as well`, and how should the index replacement be if there are more than one list?

Comment: Note that set comparisons are vastly faster than list comparisons in python.  If the elements were all unique using sets for comparison with the "in" operator would be a good way to go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the elements in `b` are unique then you can try this:

```
In [76]: a=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']

In [77]: b=['b','f','g','j']

In [78]: dic={x:i for i,x in enumerate(b)}

In [79]: dic
Out[79]: {'b': 0, 'f': 1, 'g': 2, 'j': 3}

In [81]: [dic.get(x,'-999') for x in a]
Out[81]: ['-999', 0, '-999', '-999', '-999', 1, 2, '-999', '-999', 3]
```

For repeated items you can use `defaultdict(list)`:

```
In [102]: a=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','b','h','i','f','j']

In [103]: b=['b','f','g','j','b','f']

In [104]: dic=defaultdict(list)

In [105]: for i,x in enumerate(b):
    dic[x].append(i)
   .....:     

#now convert every value(i.e list) present in dic to an iterator.

In [106]: dic={x:iter(y) for x,y in dic.items()}  

In [107]: [next(dic[x]) if x in dic else '-999' for x in a]  #call next() if the key 
                                                             #is present else use '-999'
Out[107]: ['-999', 0, '-999', '-999', '-999', 1, 2, 4, '-999', '-999', 5, 3]
```

Comment: The elements in b are unique,s o the first option would be best... but I'm getting a syntax error in line 78...

Comment: @user1735184 ignore the `[in 78]:` part, it's from the `Ipython` shell. It is similar to `>>>` of normal python interpreter.

Comment: I know :) I'm putting the syntax only :D 

dic={x:i for i,x in enumerate(b)}

And it gives the syntax error.

Comment: @user1735184 are you using python 2.6 or earlier?

Comment: @user1735184 What version of Python are you using? Probably an older one that does not support dict comprehension. You could modify it to use a loop instead.

Comment: try this `dict((x,i) for i,x in enumerate(b))`  instead of dict-comprehension in case you're using py2.6 or earlier.

Comment: Keith, I'm trying to avoid additional loops as the whole point of this exercise is to limit time and memory needed...
I am using version 2.6.6 and it works now after Ashwini's suggestion. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Something more simpler:

```
a=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']

b=['b','f','g','j']

for i,x in enumerate(a):
    a[i] = b.index(x) if x in b else -999
```

Output:

```
[-999, 0, -999, -999, -999, 1, 2, -999, -999, 3]
```

---

**Analysis:**

OP's method:

```
>>> 
len(a) = 10000
len(b) = 5000
Time = 0:00:01.063000
```

Method 1:

```
c=[]
for i,x in enumerate(a):
    c.append(b.index(x) if x in b else -999)

>>> 
len(a) = 10000
len(b) = 5000
Time = 0:00:01.109000
```

Ashwini Chaudhary method:

```
>>> 
len(a) = 10000
len(b) = 5000
Time = 0:00:00
```

Comment: This works in this example, but I see no reason to believe it would work in general, given the information from the question.

Comment: @Lattyware: Can you please explain? I am curious to know, when this may not work.

Comment: Edit: Disregard me - I see the OP does want the index, I didn't think that was specified. That said, this is very inefficient, as `list.index()` is a relatively expensive operation.

Comment: @Abhijit This may not work if the items are repeated, `index()` is always going to return `0` for `'b'` and also `.index()` is an `O(n)` operation.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: I agree that its not efficient, but OP wanted the index and if items are repeated, the item to replace with would be ambiguous